# What is the meaning of "the dogs live in clover"?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, expressions, translation

I was reading an issue of [*Atlantic Monthly*](http://books.google.com/books?id=_YoGAQAAIAAJ) from 1919 and encountered the following paragraph:

> [image: "As soon as it was dark, we went. They helped us down into their trench. What a trench! More like a palace. And don't the dogs live in clover! Coffee and rum the first thing. They chattered away, but every other word was 'Kamerad, Kamerad.' Their officer distributed leaflets, very politely. We took them — why not? Most of us could not read, so no harm was done; and why should we be rude? So we ate and drank and talked, and now it was time to go home. Half an hour later we were firing at each other. Comradeship is one thing, service is another."]

There is no further context, as these are (according to the article) translated conversations and musings of Russian soldiers overheard by a nurse. I'm not familiar with any English expression like "dogs in clover" or "live in clover" (perhaps "pig in mud").

It would seem that the "dogs" are enemy combatants (e.g. Germans) who are enjoying a much finer standard of living on the battlefield than their Russian counterparts. Is this expression used much in English, or is it a Russian or Eastern European idiom? And why "clover"?

Comment: This is two separate idioms: *dogs* for enemy, and *in clover* for living well, as you discovered. They are not connected.

Comment: Being "in clover" is an archaic form of being very well-off.  Nowadays, an English speaker would probably be more likely to say they are "as happy as a pig in slop," or "living high on the hog." In both cases, all ones needs are being met, except in the second case, where the pig probably isn't too happy about being eaten :)

Comment: General Reference - to [live in clover](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/live-be-in-clover) might be a bit dated, but it's still relatively common, and could easily be found in dictionaries.

Comment: @Affable Geek: Your American pigs really do live in clover! Our British pigs are denied such luxuries, and have to take their comfort where they find it - *"as happy as a pig in **shit**"* is as good as it gets for them!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's actually the phrase I'm more familiar with, but I censored myself out of politeness. (:

Comment: Please note: I don't oppose voting to close this as general reference. My initial search returned no leads, so I made the question. Shortly afterward I found a suitable answer. It was too late to make it a Q&A (not sure if that bypasses the 2-day period to accept your own answer), but I decided to not delete it if it helps others who stumble across this uncommon (to me, at least) phrase.

Comment: @Zairja: Others may have their own positions, but I make a definite distinction between questions I vote to close as General Reference, and those I might vote to *delete*. To me, yours is the former, but not the latter. By which I mean it's perfectly possible *you* couldn't find the answer straight off (because you were misled into including "dogs" in your search, or whatever). In short - I completely agree your decision not to delete the question, and don't object in the least to you answering it for yourself (I'll even upvote your answer to prove I'm happy with the situation! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just did some further looking. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=clover) has an entry for *clover*:

> To *be in clover* "live luxuriously" is 1710, "clover being extremely delicious and fattening to cattle" [Johnson]

Answer (score 2):

It is a mixed metaphor and a poor one at that.

The original phrase was 'cows in clover' relating to the fact that ruminants will eat it in preference to grass. It is traditionally supposed to be fattening for them as indicated by Zairja.

Example - 
*Mr. Young, who keeps a large dairy for milk in that county, feeds his cows in Clover fields (2 acres per cow) during summer...*
Horticultural Trade Journal 1866

Dogs, to my knowledge (and I'm a dog owner), are completely indifferent to clover. As you pointed out, 'dogs' is a reference to the Germans.